`xarray`: getting the parent array of a derived array
Suppose I have a DataArray called parent. Suppose that I index parent, for example: derived = parent["alpha"] (here we assume that parent has a dimension labelled "alpha").
Now, suppose I am in another context where I only have derived. Is it possible for me to get parent from derived?
Compare with:

find parent array of numpy slice array

